# PostgreSQL won't use a index on a (text) join column in some environments

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

My database development work currently involves three environments: a local PostgreSQL on Docker (`kartoza/postgis:11.5-2.5` image), and dev and production environments, which are Aurora PostgreSQL on AWS (`db.r5.xlarge` instances with version 3.1, compatible with PostgreSQL 11.6). Dev and prod are essentially equal. DB schema is handled with migrations and the data loading is automated. Errors aside, dev and prod are essentially equal. Local is as close as possible to dev and prod.

I have a query with a join from table `F` to table `S` through an FK (`F.s_id` -> `S.s_id`). Both in my local and production environments the query performs well enough, but in dev it happens to be x3 slower. After seeing the execution plans, the problem is that join. In dev and prod, the index is used on a Bitmap Heap Scan:

```
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on f f  (cost=769.47..28650.46 rows=15911 width=94) (actual time=93.371..93.889 rows=223 loops=19)
      Recheck Cond: (s_id = s_2.s_id)
      Filter: ((split_part(split_part(region_id, '-'::text, 2), '.'::text, 1) ~~ 'MX%'::text) AND (((COALESCE(f_date, r_date) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone)) OR ((COALESCE(f_date, r_date) >= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) OR (((f_date IS NULL) OR (f_date_end IS NOT NULL)) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date_end) IS NOT NULL) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date_end, r_date_end) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))))
      Rows Removed by Filter: 603 
      Heap Blocks: exact=10146
      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on f_s_id_idx  (cost=0.00..765.49 rows=36645 width=0) (actual time=0.931..0.931 rows=1587 loops=19)
            Index Cond: (s_id = s_2.s_id)
```

Nevertheless, in dev, a Seq scan is performed:

```
->  Hash Join  (cost=0.58..694942.27 rows=285254 width=96) (actual time=9910.557..9922.318 rows=4228 loops=1)
      Hash Cond: (f.s_id = s_2.s_id)
      ->  Seq Scan on f f  (cost=0.00..672953.32 rows=5102885 width=94) (actual time=0.160..9556.369 rows=4201870 loops=1)
            Filter: ((split_part(split_part(region_id, '-'::text, 2), '.'::text, 1) ~~ 'MX%'::text) AND (((COALESCE(f_date, r_date) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone)) OR ((COALESCE(f_date, r_date) >= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) OR (((f_date IS NULL) OR (f_date_end IS NOT NULL)) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date_end) IS NOT NULL) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date_end, r_date_end) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))))
            Rows Removed by Filter: 7541863
      ->  Hash  (cost=0.36..0.36 rows=18 width=64) (actual time=0.064..0.064 rows=19 loops=1)
            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
            ->  CTE Scan on allowed_ss s_2  (cost=0.00..0.36 rows=18 width=64) (actual time=0.044..0.060 rows=19 loops=1
```

I've tried...

- `VACUUM ANALYZE` to be sure that stats are updated.
- `CLUSTER` by the `f_s_id_idx` index so the storage is optimal for that index
- Dropping and recreating `f_s_id_idx`.

No matter what I try, the index is not used in dev, not even disabling seq scan. With seq scan disabled, a index on the complicated dates check is performed instead:

```
->  Hash Join  (cost=303647.45..808516.29 rows=285254 width=96) (actual time=5208.611..5214.111 rows=4228 loops=1)
      Hash Cond: (f.s_id = s_2.s_id)
      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on f f  (cost=303646.86..786527.35 rows=5102885 width=94) (actual time=1513.315..4836.337 rows=4201870 loops=1)
            Recheck Cond: (((COALESCE(f_date, r_date) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone)) OR ((COALESCE(f_date, r_date) >= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) OR ((COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date_end, r_date_end) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))) 
            Filter: ((split_part(split_part(region_id, '-'::text, 2), '.'::text, 1) ~~ 'MX%'::text) AND (((COALESCE(f_date, r_date) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone)) OR ((COALESCE(f_date, r_date) >= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) OR (((f_date IS NULL) OR (f_date_end IS NOT NULL)) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date_end) IS NOT NULL) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date_end, r_date_end) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))))
            Rows Removed by Filter: 4341
            Heap Blocks: exact=117252
            ->  BitmapOr  (cost=303646.86..303646.86 rows=5895338 width=0) (actual time=1489.570..1489.571 rows=0 loops=1)
                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on f_dates_idx  (cost=0.00..103966.71 rows=4092615 width=0) (actual time=653.589..653.589 rows=4101547 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: ((COALESCE(f_date, r_date) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone))
                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on f_dates_idx  (cost=0.00..1495.75 rows=58719 width=0) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: ((COALESCE(f_date, r_date) >= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on f_dates_idx  (cost=0.00..194357.24 rows=1744004 width=0) (actual time=835.968..835.968 rows=104702 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: ((COALESCE(f_date, r_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(f_date_end, r_date_end) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
      ->  Hash  (cost=0.36..0.36 rows=18 width=64) (actual time=0.064..0.064 rows=19 loops=1)
            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
            ->  CTE Scan on allowed_ss s_2  (cost=0.00..0.36 rows=18 width=64) (actual time=0.051..0.060 rows=19 loops=1)
```

`WORK_MEM` is already pretty high: 256MB.
`STATISTICS` for that column is also quite high, 1000, greater than the current number of different values.

BTW, this is how the index is created:

```
create index f_s_id_idx on f(s_id)
```

There's another index at that column that includes `text_pattern_ops` for `like-pattern` searches, but this one was added for equality (which is the comparison used at the index) operations.

EDIT: after @Laurenz request, this is the full plan of the fast query (with the actual names, in the previous one I had simplified/anonymized them):

```
ash Join  (cost=617711.37..617726.42 rows=250 width=96) (actual time=1828.947..1828.959 rows=32 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (r.region_id = sub2.region_id)
  CTE public_regions
    ->  Hash Join  (cost=22.47..29.07 rows=250 width=61) (actual time=1.034..1.136 rows=32 loops=1)
          Hash Cond: (r_1.source_id = s.source_id)
          ->  Index Only Scan using regions_region_id_index on regions r_1  (cost=0.56..4.58 rows=266 width=40) (actual time=0.013..0.056 rows=32 loops=1)
                Index Cond: ((region_id ~>=~ 'TIMXST-MX'::text) AND (region_id ~<~ 'TIMXST-MY'::text))
                Filter: (region_id ~~ 'TIMXST-MX%'::text)
                Heap Fetches: 32
          ->  Hash  (cost=17.11..17.11 rows=384 width=23) (actual time=1.009..1.009 rows=338 loops=1)
                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 27kB
                ->  Seq Scan on sources s  (cost=0.00..17.11 rows=384 width=23) (actual time=0.473..0.968 rows=338 loops=1)
                      Filter: (public OR (provider_id = ANY ('{SSSSSSSS,WWWWWWW}'::text[])))
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 3
  CTE ftvs
    ->  Function Scan on _two_dimensional_array_to_one_dimensional t  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=12) (actual time=0.107..0.110 rows=25 loops=1)
  CTE allowed_sources
    ->  Seq Scan on sources s_1  (cost=0.00..18.13 rows=21 width=31) (actual time=0.029..0.111 rows=19 loops=1)
          Filter: ((public OR (provider_id = ANY ('{SSSSSSSS,WWWWWWW}'::text[]))) AND (provider_id = ANY ('{SSSSSSSS,WWWWWWW}'::text[])))
          Rows Removed by Filter: 322
  CTE filtered_facts
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=611430.07..616233.39 rows=41768 width=112) (actual time=1807.723..1812.385 rows=2421 loops=1)
          Group Key: f.region_id, f.fact_type_id, f.fact_type_version, f.fact_subtype_id, s_2.provider_id
          ->  Sort  (cost=611430.07..611534.49 rows=41768 width=96) (actual time=1807.690..1808.326 rows=4228 loops=1)
                Sort Key: f.region_id, f.fact_type_id, f.fact_type_version, f.fact_subtype_id, s_2.provider_id
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 787kB
                ->  Hash Join  (cost=802.47..608224.35 rows=41768 width=96) (actual time=465.740..1787.072 rows=4228 loops=1)
                      Hash Cond: ((f.fact_type_id = ftvs.t) AND (f.fact_type_version = ftvs.v) AND (f.fact_subtype_id = ftvs.s))
                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=769.47..605001.34 rows=334141 width=96) (actual time=465.603..1785.045 rows=4228 loops=1)
                            ->  CTE Scan on allowed_sources s_2  (cost=0.00..0.42 rows=21 width=64) (actual time=0.030..0.174 rows=19 loops=1)
                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on facts f  (cost=769.47..28650.46 rows=15911 width=94) (actual time=93.371..93.889 rows=223 loops=19)
                                  Recheck Cond: (source_id = s_2.source_id)
                                  Filter: ((split_part(split_part(region_id, '-'::text, 2), '.'::text, 1) ~~ 'MX%'::text) AND (((COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) <= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone)) OR ((COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) >= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) OR (((fact_date IS NULL) OR (fact_date_end IS NOT NULL)) AND (COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date_end) IS NOT NULL) AND (COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(fact_date_end, reported_date_end) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))))
                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 603
                                  Heap Blocks: exact=10146
                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on facts_source_id_idx  (cost=0.00..765.49 rows=36645 width=0) (actual time=0.931..0.931 rows=1587 loops=19)
                                        Index Cond: (source_id = s_2.source_id)
                      ->  Hash  (cost=29.50..29.50 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=0.129..0.129 rows=25 loops=1)
                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                            ->  HashAggregate  (cost=27.50..29.50 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=0.122..0.125 rows=25 loops=1)
                                  Group Key: ftvs.t, ftvs.v, ftvs.s
                                  ->  CTE Scan on ftvs  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=12) (actual time=0.108..0.116 rows=25 loops=1)
```

BTW, if you see the fast plan, it's overestimating the number of rows. That might be a cause for seq scan being used because of a minor difference somewhere else, but I don't know what else could I do to improve the stats regarding that column.

Full slow plan:

```
    Hash Join  (cost=705764.38..705772.86 rows=198 width=96) (actual time=9964.327..9964.344 rows=32 loops=1)
      Hash Cond: (r.region_id = acbp.region_id)
      CTE public_regions
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=20.82..27.42 rows=250 width=61) (actual time=0.155..0.191 rows=32 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (r_1.source_id = s.source_id)
              ->  Index Only Scan using regions_region_id_index on regions r_1  (cost=0.56..4.58 rows=266 width=40) (actual time=0.017..0.027 rows=32 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((region_id ~>=~ 'TIMXST-MX'::text) AND (region_id ~<~ 'TIMXST-MY'::text))
                    Filter: (region_id ~~ 'TIMXST-MX%'::text)
                    Heap Fetches: 0
              ->  Hash  (cost=16.26..16.26 rows=320 width=23) (actual time=0.132..0.132 rows=338 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 27kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on sources s  (cost=0.00..16.26 rows=320 width=23) (actual time=0.006..0.083 rows=338 loops=1)
                          Filter: (public OR (provider_id = ANY ('{SSSSSSSS,WWWWWWW}'::text[])))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 3
      CTE ftvs
        ->  Function Scan on _two_dimensional_array_to_one_dimensional t  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=12) (actual time=0.124..0.128 rows=25 loops=1)
      CTE allowed_sources
        ->  Seq Scan on sources s_1  (cost=0.00..17.12 rows=18 width=31) (actual time=0.043..0.053 rows=19 loops=1)
              Filter: ((public OR (provider_id = ANY ('{SSSSSSSS,WWWWWWW}'::text[]))) AND (provider_id = ANY ('{SSSSSSSS,WWWWWWW}'::text[])))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 322
      CTE filtered_facts
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=700394.56..704495.12 rows=35657 width=112) (actual time=9942.762..9946.578 rows=2421 loops=1)
              Group Key: f.region_id, f.fact_type_id, f.fact_type_version, f.fact_subtype_id, s_2.provider_id
              ->  Sort  (cost=700394.56..700483.70 rows=35657 width=96) (actual time=9942.731..9942.932 rows=4228 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: f.region_id, f.fact_type_id, f.fact_type_version, f.fact_subtype_id, s_2.provider_id
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 787kB
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=33.59..697698.55 rows=35657 width=96) (actual time=9910.733..9923.439 rows=4228 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: ((f.fact_type_id = ftvs.t) AND (f.fact_type_version = ftvs.v) AND (f.fact_subtype_id = ftvs.s))
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=0.58..694942.27 rows=285254 width=96) (actual time=9910.557..9922.318 rows=4228 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (f.source_id = s_2.source_id)
                                ->  Seq Scan on facts f  (cost=0.00..672953.32 rows=5102885 width=94) (actual time=0.160..9556.369 rows=4201870 loops=1)
                                      Filter: ((split_part(split_part(region_id, '-'::text, 2), '.'::text, 1) ~~ 'MX%'::text) AND (((COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) <= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone)) OR ((COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) >= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) OR (((fact_date IS NULL) OR (fact_date_end IS NOT NULL)) AND (COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date_end) IS NOT NULL) AND (COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(fact_date_end, reported_date_end) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 7541863
                                ->  Hash  (cost=0.36..0.36 rows=18 width=64) (actual time=0.064..0.064 rows=19 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                                      ->  CTE Scan on allowed_sources s_2  (cost=0.00..0.36 rows=18 width=64) (actual time=0.044..0.060 rows=19 loops=1)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=29.50..29.50 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=0.157..0.157 rows=25 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                                ->  HashAggregate  (cost=27.50..29.50 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=0.146..0.151 rows=25 loops=1)
                                      Group Key: ftvs.t, ftvs.v, ftvs.s
                                      ->  CTE Scan on ftvs  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=12) (actual time=0.127..0.136 rows=25 loops=1)
      CTE fact_counts
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1172.20..1177.10 rows=178 width=128) (actual time=9963.271..9963.843 rows=72 loops=1)
              Group Key: r3.region_id, ff.provider_id, (concat(ff.fact_type_id, '-', ff.fact_type_version, '-', ff.fact_subtype_id))
              ->  Sort  (cost=1172.20..1172.65 rows=178 width=112) (actual time=9963.261..9963.368 rows=2421 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: r3.region_id, ff.provider_id, (concat(ff.fact_type_id, '-', ff.fact_type_version, '-', ff.fact_subtype_id))
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 286kB
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1165.55 rows=178 width=112) (actual time=9942.930..9961.788 rows=2421 loops=1)
                          Join Filter: (ff.region_id_natural_id ~~ r3.region_id_pattern)
                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 75051
                          ->  CTE Scan on public_regions r3  (cost=0.00..6.25 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.157..0.206 rows=32 loops=1)
                                Filter: ("substring"(region_id, 1, 6) = 'TIMXST'::text)
                          ->  CTE Scan on filtered_facts ff  (cost=0.00..713.14 rows=35657 width=92) (actual time=310.711..311.022 rows=2421 loops=32)
      CTE counts_by_provider
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=4.89..7.12 rows=178 width=96) (actual time=9963.974..9963.986 rows=33 loops=1)
              Group Key: fc.region_id, fc.provider_id
              ->  CTE Scan on fact_counts fc  (cost=0.00..3.56 rows=178 width=128) (actual time=9963.272..9963.871 rows=72 loops=1)
      CTE counts_by_type
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=4.89..7.12 rows=178 width=96) (actual time=0.046..0.065 rows=71 loops=1)
              Group Key: fc_1.region_id, fc_1.fact_type
              ->  CTE Scan on fact_counts fc_1  (cost=0.00..3.56 rows=178 width=96) (actual time=0.000..0.006 rows=72 loops=1)
      CTE aggregated_counts_by_provider
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=4.45..6.68 rows=178 width=64) (actual time=9964.070..9964.082 rows=32 loops=1)
              Group Key: cbp.region_id
              ->  CTE Scan on counts_by_provider cbp  (cost=0.00..3.56 rows=178 width=96) (actual time=9963.975..9963.998 rows=33 loops=1)
      ->  Hash Join  (cost=10.68..16.35 rows=222 width=96) (actual time=0.212..0.222 rows=32 loops=1)
            Hash Cond: (r.region_id = sub2.region_id)
            ->  CTE Scan on public_regions r  (cost=0.00..5.00 rows=250 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.003 rows=32 loops=1)
            ->  Hash  (cost=8.46..8.46 rows=178 width=64) (actual time=0.203..0.203 rows=32 loops=1)
                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 12kB
                  ->  Subquery Scan on sub2  (cost=4.45..8.46 rows=178 width=64) (actual time=0.177..0.192 rows=32 loops=1)
                        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=4.45..6.68 rows=178 width=64) (actual time=0.176..0.188 rows=32 loops=1)
                              Group Key: sub.region_id
                              ->  CTE Scan on counts_by_type sub  (cost=0.00..3.56 rows=178 width=96) (actual time=0.046..0.088 rows=71 loops=1)
      ->  Hash  (cost=3.56..3.56 rows=178 width=64) (actual time=9964.110..9964.110 rows=32 loops=1)
            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
            ->  CTE Scan on aggregated_counts_by_provider acbp  (cost=0.00..3.56 rows=178 width=64) (actual time=9964.072..9964.097 rows=32 loops=1)
```

More EDIT: the previous fast plan was from my local. As prod is closer to dev (it's Aurora), the production plan is more important. Here it is:

```
    Hash Join  (cost=713549.03..713557.81 rows=225 width=96) (actual time=56.873..56.889 rows=32 loops=1)
      Hash Cond: (r.region_id = acbp.region_id)
      CTE public_regions
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=21.17..27.77 rows=249 width=61) (actual time=0.151..0.200 rows=32 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (r_1.source_id = s.source_id)
              ->  Index Only Scan using regions_region_id_index on regions r_1  (cost=0.56..4.58 rows=266 width=40) (actual time=0.013..0.034 rows=32 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((region_id ~>=~ 'TIMXST-MX'::text) AND (region_id ~<~ 'TIMXST-MY'::text))
                    Filter: (region_id ~~ 'TIMXST-MX%'::text)
                    Heap Fetches: 0
              ->  Hash  (cost=16.45..16.45 rows=333 width=23) (actual time=0.132..0.132 rows=338 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 27kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on sources s  (cost=0.00..16.45 rows=333 width=23) (actual time=0.005..0.083 rows=338 loops=1)
                          Filter: (public OR (provider_id = ANY ('{SSSSSSSS,WWWWWWW}'::text[])))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 3
      CTE ftvs
        ->  Function Scan on _two_dimensional_array_to_one_dimensional t  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=12) (actual time=0.070..0.074 rows=25 loops=1)
      CTE allowed_sources
        ->  Seq Scan on sources s_1  (cost=0.00..17.34 rows=19 width=31) (actual time=0.004..0.081 rows=19 loops=1)
              Filter: ((public OR (provider_id = ANY ('{SSSSSSSS,WWWWWWW}'::text[]))) AND (provider_id = ANY ('{SSSSSSSS,WWWWWWW}'::text[])))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 322
      CTE filtered_facts
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=707831.57..712200.08 rows=37987 width=112) (actual time=35.313..39.184 rows=2421 loops=1)
              Group Key: f.region_id, f.fact_type_id, f.fact_type_version, f.fact_subtype_id, s_2.provider_id
              ->  Sort  (cost=707831.57..707926.54 rows=37987 width=96) (actual time=35.279..35.523 rows=4228 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: f.region_id, f.fact_type_id, f.fact_type_version, f.fact_subtype_id, s_2.provider_id
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 787kB
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=33.56..704942.05 rows=37987 width=96) (actual time=0.136..16.191 rows=4228 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: ((f.fact_type_id = ftvs.t) AND (f.fact_type_version = ftvs.v) AND (f.fact_subtype_id = ftvs.s))
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..702007.78 rows=303897 width=96) (actual time=0.036..15.181 rows=4228 loops=1)
                                ->  CTE Scan on allowed_sources s_2  (cost=0.00..0.38 rows=19 width=64) (actual time=0.005..0.093 rows=19 loops=1)
                                ->  Index Scan using facts_source_id_idx on facts f  (cost=0.56..36787.81 rows=15995 width=94) (actual time=0.507..0.768 rows=223 loops=19)
                                      Index Cond: (source_id = s_2.source_id)
                                      Filter: ((split_part(split_part(region_id, '-'::text, 2), '.'::text, 1) ~~ 'MX%'::text) AND (((COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) <= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone)) OR ((COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) >= '2020-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) OR (((fact_date IS NULL) OR (fact_date_end IS NOT NULL)) AND (COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date_end) IS NOT NULL) AND (COALESCE(fact_date, reported_date) <= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (COALESCE(fact_date_end, reported_date_end) >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 603
                          ->  Hash  (cost=29.50..29.50 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=0.095..0.095 rows=25 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                                ->  HashAggregate  (cost=27.50..29.50 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=0.087..0.091 rows=25 loops=1)
                                      Group Key: ftvs.t, ftvs.v, ftvs.s
                                      ->  CTE Scan on ftvs  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=12) (actual time=0.071..0.080 rows=25 loops=1)
      CTE fact_counts
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1248.47..1253.69 rows=190 width=128) (actual time=55.806..56.378 rows=72 loops=1)
              Group Key: r3.region_id, ff.provider_id, (concat(ff.fact_type_id, '-', ff.fact_type_version, '-', ff.fact_subtype_id))
              ->  Sort  (cost=1248.47..1248.94 rows=190 width=112) (actual time=55.795..55.902 rows=2421 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: r3.region_id, ff.provider_id, (concat(ff.fact_type_id, '-', ff.fact_type_version, '-', ff.fact_subtype_id))
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 286kB
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1241.28 rows=190 width=112) (actual time=35.477..54.300 rows=2421 loops=1)
                          Join Filter: (ff.region_id_natural_id ~~ r3.region_id_pattern)
                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 75051
                          ->  CTE Scan on public_regions r3  (cost=0.00..6.23 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.153..0.215 rows=32 loops=1)
                                Filter: ("substring"(region_id, 1, 6) = 'TIMXST'::text)
                          ->  CTE Scan on filtered_facts ff  (cost=0.00..759.74 rows=37987 width=92) (actual time=1.104..1.417 rows=2421 loops=32)
      CTE counts_by_provider
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=5.23..7.60 rows=190 width=96) (actual time=56.520..56.532 rows=33 loops=1)
              Group Key: fc.region_id, fc.provider_id
              ->  CTE Scan on fact_counts fc  (cost=0.00..3.80 rows=190 width=128) (actual time=55.807..56.408 rows=72 loops=1)
      CTE counts_by_type
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=5.23..7.60 rows=190 width=96) (actual time=0.044..0.064 rows=71 loops=1)
              Group Key: fc_1.region_id, fc_1.fact_type
              ->  CTE Scan on fact_counts fc_1  (cost=0.00..3.80 rows=190 width=96) (actual time=0.000..0.005 rows=72 loops=1)
      CTE aggregated_counts_by_provider
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=4.75..7.12 rows=190 width=64) (actual time=56.620..56.633 rows=32 loops=1)
              Group Key: cbp.region_id
              ->  CTE Scan on counts_by_provider cbp  (cost=0.00..3.80 rows=190 width=96) (actual time=56.521..56.545 rows=33 loops=1)
      ->  Hash Join  (cost=11.40..17.04 rows=237 width=96) (actual time=0.206..0.215 rows=32 loops=1)
            Hash Cond: (r.region_id = sub2.region_id)
            ->  CTE Scan on public_regions r  (cost=0.00..4.98 rows=249 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.003 rows=32 loops=1)
            ->  Hash  (cost=9.03..9.03 rows=190 width=64) (actual time=0.197..0.197 rows=32 loops=1)
                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 12kB
                  ->  Subquery Scan on sub2  (cost=4.75..9.03 rows=190 width=64) (actual time=0.175..0.190 rows=32 loops=1)
                        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=4.75..7.12 rows=190 width=64) (actual time=0.174..0.186 rows=32 loops=1)
                              Group Key: sub.region_id
                              ->  CTE Scan on counts_by_type sub  (cost=0.00..3.80 rows=190 width=96) (actual time=0.045..0.085 rows=71 loops=1)
      ->  Hash  (cost=3.80..3.80 rows=190 width=64) (actual time=56.662..56.662 rows=32 loops=1)
            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
            ->  CTE Scan on aggregated_counts_by_provider acbp  (cost=0.00..3.80 rows=190 width=64) (actual time=56.622..56.644 rows=32 loops=1)
```

As you see, the reading of `filtered_facts` is even better than in local, with an index scan instead of bitmap heap scan.

Comment: Please post the complete execution plan of the fast query.

Comment: There you have, Laurenz!

Comment: BTW, if you see the fast plan, it's overestimating the number of rows. That might be a cause for seq scan being used because of a minor difference somewhere else, but I don't know what else could I do to improve the stats regarding that column.

Comment: Oh; I thought that the slow plan was complete. Since it is not, could you post the full slow plan too?

Comment: Sure, done! And thanks! :)

Comment: I just added the production plan as well. The other "fast plan" was from my local environment.

Answer (score 1):

Ey... I finally addressed it by running just an `ANALYZE`. I never run `ANALYZE` alone, I always do `VACUUM ANALYZE`. AFAIK, doing it should clean garbage *and* update the stats. I read somewhere that Aurora doesn't update the stats while vacuum is being run, so I gave this a try. Maybe something is stuck under the hood and the stats weren't properly updated :shrug:

Comment: I was facing this issue and running ANALYZE command solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On the fast system, the index scan scans 19*(603+223) = 15694 rows from `facts` to find 19*223 = 4237 rows. On the slow system, all 7541863 + 4201870 = 11743733 rows of `facts` are scanned to find 4201870 rows.

If the percentage of result rows returned is high enough, a sequential scan is the most efficient access strategy.

So the difference is because the data in the databases are different. I see no reason to suspect that PostgreSQL is doing the wrong thing here.

Comment: Uhm... Maybe I'm not getting something. If you see the result of the hash join between facts and sources, you get 4228 rows in all environments, the data is the same.

Comment: In addition, in the slow one, disabling the seq scan has proven to be faster (while not as fast as the right one, as a different index is being used). Regarding your 4201870 mention in the slow one, that's the problem: the join with sources is way more selective, so with right stats, it should be chosen first, so the result space is way lower.